# ECC ram in non-ECC motherboard

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i7, desktop-computer, ecc

We want to create a computer with i7-2600k (Z68 chipset) and 32 GB ram. After some googling we found out that this can only be done with 4x8GB modules. We can choose from:

- Samsung nonECC
- A-DATA nonECC
- Kingston ECC
- Crucial ECC

with Crucial and Kingston being the cheapest.

Will it work if we place 4x8GB ECC non buffered ram into a non-server LGA-1155? We are not interested in ECC, our goal is just a working computer with 32 GB ram.

Comment: I'm looking to do the exact same thing. My supplier doesn't offer 8GB DIMM that are unregistered, non-ECC. If you happen to get it working this way, please update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some* non-ECC supporting motherboards will take ECC memory and work - it's a bit hit-and-miss - but if you want to play safe, stick to the general specs recommended by the motherboard manufacturer or try with some ECC if you happen to have some to hand.